# Parse server - get related classes - rest api

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

Assuming i have a class User and a class Profile

The profile class has a field called "sex" and a field called "user" which is a pointer to user class.

If i get the profile endpoint with : https://myapi.back4app.io/classes/Profile i can get the Profile object:

```js
{
    "results": [
        {
            "objectId": "sIE6lOZP7R",
            "user": {
                "__type": "Pointer",
                "className": "_User",
                "objectId": "asP3EFYSR4"
            },
            "sex": "male",
            "createdAt": "2020-05-25T17:15:49.324Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-05-25T17:15:49.324Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

and if i want to include the user of this profile, i can include with: https://myapi.back4app.io/classes/Perfil?include=user so i get:

```js
{
    "results": [
        {
            "objectId": "sIE6lOZP7R",
            "user": {
                "objectId": "asP3EFYSR4",
                "username": "fabiojansen",
                "createdAt": "2020-05-25T17:15:16.273Z",
                "updatedAt": "2020-05-25T17:15:16.273Z",
                "ACL": {
                    "*": {
                        "read": true
                    },
                    "asP3EFYSR4": {
                        "read": true,
                        "write": true
                    }
                },
                "__type": "Object",
                "className": "_User"
            },
            "sex": "male",
            "createdAt": "2020-05-25T17:15:49.324Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-05-25T17:15:49.324Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

Its ok, but if i want to get all the users, with the profile information in one query? Its possible? In my User class, i dont have any pointer to Profile class, only in profile class.

Is there any way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

1) You can use an `aggregate` pipeline and `$lookup` the user in the `Perfil` class which performs a `LEFT JOIN`. However, this will not return an array of `Parse.Object`, you'd have to parse the results manually. From the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/):

```
{
   $lookup:
     {
       from: <collection to join>,
       localField: <field from the input documents>,
       foreignField: <field from the documents of the "from" collection>,
       as: <output array field>
     }
}
```

2) You can do 2 requests by first getting all the users and then getting all their profiles by user IDs.

3) You can change your data model and add a pointer to `Perfil` in your `User` class. If you are running this query at scale it may be beneficial.